# Graph database and javascript

Tags: javascript, apache, graph-databases

I would like to implement a simple web application in apache(php or python) with an open source `Graph database`.

I would like also to query the "Graph database" using just `javascript` (client). It will be possible?

Which Graph database do you suggest me to use for this (the most simple)?

Answer (score 1):

[Neo4J](http://neo4j.org/) has a [REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api.html). That should allow you to interact with the database from most environments.

Answer (score 0):

I would heavily recommend using [ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com). They offer an official and well supported [JS driver](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/drivers/) and their query language (AQL) is both semantically [more pleasant and productive](https://www.arangodb.com/comparing-arangodb-aql-neo4j-cypher/) than alternatives such as gremlin and Neo4J's Cypher.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple and beginner friendly option, I suggest using Neo4j as the graph database. Neo4j is an open source, highly popular graph database known for its ease of use and flexibility. It has excellent support for various programming languages, including PHP and Python, making it a suitable choice for integrating with Apache web servers.

With Neo4j's JavaScript driver (such as neo4j-driver), you can easily query the graph database directly from the client-side JavaScript code. This enables you to perform real-time queries and display graph data on your web application without the need for server-side intervention.